# How can I use <bind> within a loop while using MyBatis?

Tags: mybatis

I wanted to build a sql like "(column like 'a%' or column like 'b%' or ...)" and a,b,etc. are elements in a collection.
So I came up with xml file like this

```
<foreach item="item" collection="items" open="(" separator=" or " close=")">
<bind name="pattern" value="item + '%'" />
column like #{pattern}
</foreach
```

But it didn't work out as I thought it would be.
The sql was like "(column like 'c%' or column like 'c%' or ...)" which c is the last element in the collection.
Now I use a CONCAT function to do the job.

```
column like CONCAT(#{pattern},'%')
```

Is there other good ways to do the job?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you do `CONCAT(#{pattern}, '%')` or `CONCAT(#{item}, '%')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known limitation i.e. `<bind />` cannot be used inside `<foreach />` and there is an open [issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/575).
Using CONCAT is a good workaround for now.